# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 after using generics in graph classes - swift3

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, xcode8

I was trying to create a generic Graph structure in swift 3. The problem is that the compiler fails with the following message:

`While emitting IR SIL function ... for 'init' at .../Graph.swift:48:21`

The line the compiler points at is the init method of `Edge` class:

```swift
public class Edge<T: Hashable, V: Vertex<T>> {
    public var source: V
    public var destination: V
    public let weight: Double?

    required public init(source: V, destination: V, weight: Double? = nil) {
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        self.weight = weight
    }
}
```

I think I might be a problem with the usage of generics.
Here are the classes involved:

```swift
public class Vertex<T: Hashable> {
    var data: T

    required public init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

extension Vertex: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(data)".hashValue
    }

    static public func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
}

extension Vertex: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "\(data)"
    }
}

// MARK: - Edge

public enum EdgeType {
    case directed, undirected
}

public class Edge<T: Hashable, V: Vertex<T>> {
    public var source: V
    public var destination: V
    public let weight: Double?

    required public init(source: V, destination: V, weight: Double? = nil) {
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        self.weight = weight
    }
}

extension Edge: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(source)\(destination)\(weight)".hashValue
    }

    // We need to overload the equals operator because Hashable implements Equatable
    static public func ==(lhs: Edge<T, V>, rhs: Edge<T, V>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.source == rhs.source && lhs.destination == rhs.destination && lhs.weight == rhs.weight
    }
}
```

Those two classes are used by a generic `AdjacencyList<T: Hashable, V: Vertex<T>, E: Edge<T, V>>`

Thank you

Comment: Do you really want Edge to be a class?

Comment: Well yes, I don't know. I may try with a struct to see if the compiler does not complain. But that's cleaner with a class or struct

Comment: With Edge declared as struct, it will compile just fine. You will as well need to remove required keyword from init of Edge .

Comment: But then you cannot inherit from a struct, plus a struct is passed as value and not by reference. I don't think a struct if the best way to handle a graph. And I don't think this is a solution to the problem, but a workaround

Comment: Indeed this cannot be done: `public struct Edge<T: Hashable, V: Vertex<T>>` the compiler gives this: `Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Vertex<T>'`

Comment: structs are passed by value, but any references inside struct are passed by reference. source and destination, being classes, will be passed by reference even if Edge is a struct.

Comment: Look like you changed Vertex also into struct. Keep Vertex as class and Edge as struct.

Comment: Try to remove 'V' from generic description like this: 'public class Edge<T: Hashable> {
    public var source: Vertex<T> ...'.

Comment: The problem with removing 'V' from Edge is that doing so means that every Edge instance will hold the basic type Vertex<T> not a class inheriting from Vertex. I could probably use that anyway casting Vertex<T> to an other type. But I can find a better solution I would be better

Comment: I cannot change neither Edge nor Vertex to a struct because then I cannot create classes the inherit from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell you why your code is crashing. You'd better send a bug report for this issue. But I have a workaround for you:

```
public protocol VertexType: Hashable {
    associatedtype DataType
    var data: DataType { get set }
}

public class Vertex<T: Hashable>: VertexType {
    public var data: T

    required public init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

extension Vertex {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(data)".hashValue
    }

    static public func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
}

extension Vertex: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "\(data)"
    }
}

// MARK: - Edge

public class Edge<V: VertexType> {
    public var source: V
    public var destination: V
    public let weight: Double?

    required public init(source: V, destination: V, weight: Double? = nil) {
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        self.weight = weight
    }
}

extension Edge: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(source)\(destination)\(weight)".hashValue
    }

    // We need to overload the equals operator because Hashable implements Equatable
    static public func ==(lhs: Edge<V>, rhs: Edge<V>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.source == rhs.source && lhs.destination == rhs.destination && lhs.weight == rhs.weight
    }
}
```

And now you can use `Vertex` subclasses as you wanted:

```
public class IntVertex: Vertex<Int> {}

Edge(source: IntVertex(data: 1), destination: IntVertex(data: 2))
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like this was fixed in **Swift 3.1**. At least similar [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3430) not crashing Xcode 8.3 anymore. So probably it will be enough to update your Xcode.

Comment: As soon as I get home, I'll try and accept your answer if true. Thank you!